# "godep save" Not Adding New Packages

Tags: go, godeps

I'm trying to submit a pull request to a golang project. I've never used `godep` before and it's giving me some grief.

In [this commit](https://github.com/pnovotnak/minikube/commit/b3455c17f58b58d73a90fdc730846d96d67ea39a) I added an import--github.com/Parallels/docker-machine-parallels but `godep save` is not adding it to Godeps/Godeps.json

```
~/.../github.com/pnovotnak/minikube (feat/parallels) $ git status
On branch feat/parallels
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So, working directory seems to be clean, however;

```
~/.../github.com/pnovotnak/minikube (feat/parallels) $ godep save ./...
godep: no buildable Go source files in /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/github.com/pnovotnak/minikube/vendor/github.com/vishvananda/netlink/nl
godep: no buildable Go source files in /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/github.com/pnovotnak/minikube/vendor/golang.org/x/exp/inotify
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/cmd/localkube/cmd
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/cmd/minikube/cmd
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/localkube
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/cluster
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/config
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/constants
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/kubeconfig
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/notify
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/sshutil
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/tests
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/util
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/pkg/version
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/bitbucket.org/ww/goautoneg
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/BurntSushi/toml
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/ClusterHQ/flocker-go
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/appc/cni/libcni
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/appc/cni/pkg/invoke
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/appc/cni/pkg/types
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/appc/spec/schema
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/armon/go-metrics
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/elb
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/beorn7/perks/quantile
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/blang/semver
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/boltdb/bolt
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/alarm
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/wal
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/coreos/go-etcd/etcd
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/coreos/go-oidc/oidc
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/coreos/go-semver/semver
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/coreos/go-systemd/activation
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/coreos/go-systemd/unit
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/coreos/pkg/capnslog
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/coreos/pkg/health
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/coreos/pkg/httputil
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/coreos/pkg/timeutil
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/coreos/rkt/api/v1alpha
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/distribution/digest
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/distribution/reference
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/jsonmessage
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/units
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/engine-api/client
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/engine-api/types
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/sockets
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/tlsconfig
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/go-units
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/commands/mcndirs
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/drivers/errdriver
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/drivers/none
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/drivers/virtualbox
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/drivers/vmwarefusion
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/libmachine
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/machine/version
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/docker/spdystream
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/evanphx/json-patch
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/ghodss/yaml
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/go-ini/ini
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/godbus/dbus
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/golang/glog
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/golang/groupcache/lru
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/google/btree
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/events
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/utils
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/google/gofuzz
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/go-msgpack/codec
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/hcl
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/raft
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/raft-boltdb
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/hawkular/hawkular-client-go/metrics
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/imdario/mergo
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/influxql
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/meta
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/snapshot
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/toml
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/tsdb
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/jonboulle/clockwork
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/juju/ratelimit
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/magiconair/properties
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/matttproud/golang_protobuf_extensions/pbutil
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/mesos/mesos-go/detector
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/mesos/mesos-go/upid
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/miekg/dns
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/mxk/go-flowrate/flowrate
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/pborman/uuid
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/pkg/browser
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/prometheus/client_model/go
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/prometheus/common/expfmt
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/prometheus/common/internal/bitbucket.org/ww/goautoneg
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/prometheus/common/model
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/prometheus/procfs
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/rackspace/gophercloud
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/robfig/cron
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/samalba/dockerclient
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/skynetservices/skydns/backends/etcd
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/skynetservices/skydns/singleflight
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/spf13/cast
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/spf13/jwalterweatherman
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/spf13/pflag
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/spf13/viper
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/ugorji/go/codec
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/vmware/govmomi
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/github.com/xiang90/probing
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/go4.org/errorutil
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/google.golang.org/api/cloudmonitoring/v2beta2
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/google.golang.org/api/container/v1
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/google.golang.org/api/gensupport
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/google.golang.org/api/googleapi
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/google.golang.org/cloud/compute/metadata
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/google.golang.org/cloud/internal
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/gopkg.in/gcfg.v1
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/gopkg.in/inf.v0
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/gopkg.in/yaml.v2
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/heapster/metrics/api/v1/types
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/heapster/metrics/apis/metrics/v1alpha1
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-apiserver/app
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-controller-manager/app
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-proxy/app
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubelet/app
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/admission
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apimachinery
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/abac
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/rbac
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/auth/authenticator
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/auth/authorizer
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/auth/handlers
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/auth/user
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/capabilities
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/unversioned
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/cloudprovider
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/controller
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/conversion
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/credentialprovider
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/fieldpath
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/fields
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/genericapiserver
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/healthz
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/httplog
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/labels
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/master
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/probe
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/proxy
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/quota
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/registry/cachesize
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/registry/thirdpartyresourcedata
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/runtime
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/security/podsecuritypolicy
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/securitycontext
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/serviceaccount
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/ssh
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/storage
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/types
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/ui
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/version
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/volume
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/cmd/kube-scheduler/app
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/admission/admit
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/admission/serviceaccount
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/auth/authenticator/password/keystone
...
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/auth/authorizer/rbac
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/auth/authorizer/webhook
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/client/auth
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/webhook
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/third_party/forked/json
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/third_party/forked/reflect
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/third_party/golang/expansion
godep: dirty working tree (please commit changes): /Users/pnovotnak/go/src/k8s.io/minikube/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/third_party/golang/netutil
godep: error loading dependencies
```

Before I start tearing my hair out with dtruss / attaching a go debugger to godep source code I figured I'd ask the community... WTH am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `godep save ./...`?

Comment: Sorry, my question was pretty bad :\ I added some git context and output from the program.

Comment: It seems that godep does not complain about you repo, but about packages which you vendor. It might happen that they are also subrepositories of your project.
Could you run `git status` in some package which is said to have dirty working tree? In their vendored path and their original import path both.

Comment: Hey, godep can be a little clunky here :(
This is basically the process I use for adding things to minikube.

* Create a clean gopath. You can make a new directory somewhere, just for the update (mkdir ~/fakegopath; export GOPATH=$HOME/fakegopath;)

* Copy your minikube directory into there (fakegopath/src/k8s.io/minikube)

* From the minikube repo, run "godep restore ./..."

* "go get" the new dependency

* edit your code to use it, build and test, etc.

* Run godep save ./...